# lending or supporting

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

Would you show me any difference between these semantically or conceptually?

**lending support** to his ideas

**Supporting** his ideas

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add to the other great answer here. I think the "lending" implies being separated from, or not owning the thing to which you support. It indicates a lack of ownership and a weaker commitment to the thing being supported.

This doesn't necessarily mean that the support being "lent" is of lesser value, but rather that there is some decoupling between the person and the cause itself. This could be done to put some distance between other people supporting the cause for a political reason, or just out of humility (which again would be the desire to diminish the magnitude of the commitment to the thing).

"I support" indicates an ownership, a firmer association implying a greater commitment of resources or shared ideals with the thing in question.

Take for example "I lend my support to the community kitchen when I can." versus "I support the community kitchen.". The latter implies a greater commitment usually, as this could literally mean that the person is providing the primary source of operating capital, human resources or something else essential to operation. As such, this automatically implies a deeper commitment to the cause in question.

Answer (score 0):

*Lending support to X* can express one giving or offering support to X, with the thing being lent the effort in providing support.  X is typically an idea, cause, person representing such, or group of people in conflict with another group.  Obviously this is not a physical thing that can be "returned" or paid back, but the idea is that the one lending support trusts the idea, cause, person, or group to return support or some type of benefit in the future, without an explicit agreement.

*Supporting X* just expresses *providing support to X* without the subtext of trust or getting something back in the future.